# How to update the view after my observable stream changes in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have one service in which I have setup a stream.

```
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Column } from './../../column.model';

@Injectable()
export class ColumnService {
  selectedColumnInstance:Column = new Column();

  // Observable selectColumn source
  private selectColumnSource = new Subject<Column>();

  // Observable selectColumn stream
  selectColumn$ = this.selectColumnSource.asObservable();

  // service command
  selectColumn(column:Column) {
    console.log(column);    
    this.selectedColumnInstance=column;
    this.selectColumnSource.next(column);
  }
}
```

I am updating this stream as:

```
this.rapidColumnService.selectColumn(this.selectedCol); //selectedCol is new value
```

Now I have a component which loads its childComponent if this columnStream is having any value:

**designer.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="selectedComponent">
  <editor component-name="value-editor" [(model)]="selectedComponent.model"></editor>
</div>
```

Now Inside my designer.component.ts, I have subscribed to this stream inside ngOnInit() lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.subscriptionColumn = this.rapidColumnService.selectColumn$.subscribe(
  selectedComponent => {
    this.selectedComponent = selectedComponent;
  });
}
```

So far so good, If I am in designerComponent , then every time I am updating column in service , the view changes.

But as soon as I redirect to other component and redirect to designer again I am not able to load the editor component.

I can see the stream getting updated in service.

I want to load editor-component every time stream gets updated.

is it the router issue?

any inputs?

thanks & regards.

Comment: there isnt a lot of information to go by here.. is selectedModel populated? does the subscription callback fire?